# Is it posible to send a post request from reactjs to expressjs and in express fetching data and sending that back to reactjs with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

Im new to redux.

In my scenario I have a input field, I use this input field to populate the body of a post request :

```
Action ===> export const fetchSearchProducts = (search) =>  (dispatch) => {


   fetch("/search", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(search),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_ITEM, payload: data }); ===> this errors out saying Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function


      // this console.log() actually returns the data im looking for
      console.log(data)
      
    });
  };
```

This post goes to a ExpressJS server and there I use "req.body.search" to populate the url field for an API fetch. "url = `https://example.nl?search=${req.body.search}`;"

up until here it seems to work....

Now my problem is im trying to populate the state using the redux dispatch in the action..... but i keep getting this error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function

Answer (score 1):

By itself, redux doesn't support async dispatching, a middleware is needed to accomplish that. You could add any middleware that allows async dispatching like redux-thunk or a similar library.

You can check the [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#redux-middleware-and-side-effects) for more information about this.